# JXL Attempt to modify a referenced format while setting background color

Tags: java, exception, jxl

While trying to execute the below code:

```
Colour selectedColour = Colour.WHITE;
myWritableCellFormat.setBackground(selectedColour);
```

I am getting this Exception:

```
jxl.write.biff.JxlWriteException: Attempt to modify a referenced format
```

Why is this? For reference I've used the same object before these 2 lines to write a cell with another color. Is this of any importance?

Comment: did you ever find the answer to this query ?

Comment: i guess i didn't. I don't remember what I did though, but I am sure I would have answered the question myself, if I had an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to change the color for different cell, you need to create the different `WritableFont` object and have to pass to `WritableCellFormat` constructor.

i.e every time you need to create new objects for WritableFont, WritableCellFormat classes.

```
WritableFont font = new WritableFont(WritableFont.createFont("Calibri"), 11);
WritableCellFormat format = new WritableCellFormat(font);
format.setBackground(Colour.LIGHT_GREEN, Pattern.SOLID);
```